# Modifying Score text in Locate Widget of Flexviewer 2.4?

Tags: arcgis-flex-api, arcgis-flex-viewer

I want to add text where it says "score" to make it more clear that this is an address matching score.

[image]

I am using the LocateWidget_US.xml and do not think I can do it here.  I think the place to do it may be in the LocateWidget.mxml in this line????

```
 locateResult.content = getDefaultString("resultScoreText") + " " + 
 (addrCandidate.score % 1 == 0 ? addrCandidate.score : addrCandidate.score.toFixed(1));
```

Answer (score 1):

this is the code

```
locateResult.content = "Address Matching " + getDefaultString("resultScoreText") + " " + (addrCandidate.score % 1 == 0 ? addrCandidate.score : addrCandidate.score.toFixed(1));
```

to produce this:

[image]

Comment: the changed made to the code is causing the tool to not function properly, results do not display properly.  I think i need to make a change in the LocateResultDataGroup.as or the LocateResult.as.  Anyone have any idea where?

Comment: Did you make the change in the MXML and then re-compile?