# Create Custom Popup for Locate Widget

Tags: arcgis-flex-viewer, widget

Without touching the FlexBuilder app (I'm still going through the tutorials for Flex) is there a way to customize the pop-up that appears for the Locate Widget?

I am assuming that I could go into the pop-ups folder and create a popup_Locate config file of some sort? Is this correct? Or is there a better way to customize the popups that appear when selecting from the list that populates from a Locate Widget search?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this using pop-ups folder.  You may be able to go to the widgets folder > locate widget xml. and make some changes there.  If you can't do that you will need to modify the code using Flashbuilder.

This [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17117/modifying-the-score-text-in-the-locate-widget-of-flexviewer-2-4/17196#17196) to [Modifying the Score text in the Locate Widget of Flexviewer 2.4](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17117) might help.

Comment: I would like to allow users to use the 'Locate' widget to search for their address. Then when the 'Locate' graphic displays over their address I want that graphic to trigger a popup as if the user clicked at that location.

Comment: Basically, I have a 'City Council District' map. I want users to enter their address and have the Council District Layer Popup trigger with the results of their layer.

Comment: You would need to modify the source code for the Locate Widget using Flashbuilder to fire an event to query your City Layer and produce a result, not an easy task if you're new to Flex.

You could cheat and use the this [post][1] to modify the text (in Flashbuilder) to inform the user to click on the City Layer or map.  And configure the pop-up.  

Good luck. These are the limitations of the flexviewer or app builder.
  [1]: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17117/modifying-the-score-text-in-the-locate-widget-of-flexviewer-2-4/17196#17196

Comment: Yeah, I used to do Flex dev but in a very restricted environment, so I'm going through the Flex in a Week training to get back up to speed. I'll be looking back at this once I get up to speed.